# sinatra v1.4.8 not picking right port from config

Tags: sinatra, thin

I am following a course around Puppet. The instructor sets up an application machine (fedora 31) installing the following

> cowsay pasture thin sinatra......

I am really new to this and have no idea but Ok they work fine. The instructor suggest creating a service for pasture, so 2 files need to be created , 1st one

> vim /etc/pasture_config.yaml

```
---
default_character: stegosaurus
default_message: Hello From Sierac
db: postgres://pasture:jura551c@myip/pasturedb
sinatra_settings:
  :port: 80
  :server: thin
```

The 2nd file is **/etc/systemd/system/pasture.service** with the following content

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the pasture service

[Service]
Environmenti=RACK_ENV-production
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pasture start --config_file /etc/pasture_config.yaml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the service pasture.service, in the log it shows that Sinatra did not pick the right port 80, I tried another port it was the same result, here is the output when I run the service

> sudo systemctl status pasture.service ● pasture.service - Run the
> pasture service    Loaded: loaded
> (/etc/systemd/system/pasture.service; enabled; vendor preset:
> disabled)    Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-06-27 22:14:37
> CEST; 7s ago  Main PID: 1329023 (ruby-mri)
> Tasks: 1 (limit: 4610)    Memory: 32.2M    CGroup: /system.slice/pasture.service
> └─1329023 /usr/bin/ruby-mri /usr/local/bin/pasture start --config_file /etc/pasture_config.yaml
>
> Jun 27 22:14:37 puppetmaster29 systemd[1]: Started Run the pasture
> service. Jun 27 22:14:38 puppetmaster29 pasture[1329023]: == **Sinatra
> (v1.4.8) has taken the stage on 4567** for development with backup
> from Thin

As you can notice that Sinatra does not pick the port I indicated in the config file but rather it uses the default port 4567.

What is missing

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `pasture` file

```
Pasture::API.set :pasture_options, options
if options[:sinatra_settings]
    Pasture::API.set options[:sinatra_settings]
    if Pasture::API.server == 'thin' || Pasture::API.server == 'mongrel'
        require Pasture::API.server
    end
end
```

https://github.com/puppetlabs/pltraining-pasture/blob/master/bin/pasture#L23

You see that the key should be `:sinatra_settings`. Your config file is missing a `:`.

(Another thing is your service file has a `i` too much in `Environmenti` but this does not mater for this issue)

Comment: So many thanks, I added the ":" and started picking the port 80, however, the preceding variables are not taken into consideration, when I run  curl 'http://localhost/api/v1/cowsay' I get             __ 
|  |
 -- 
      \   ^__^
       \  (oo)\_______
          (__)\       )\/\
              ||----w |
              ||     ||

Comment: please checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers your comments sound more like new questions

Comment: Sir, the question is related to the same file and app, if you look  at it, the 1st 3 lines concern those I am talking about

Comment: That does not really matter stackoverflow is not a discussion forum - but feel free to formulate your follow up questions as new questions